# Complexity of chaining methods in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I have a problem to determine the complexity of my algorithm because it use **features of ES6** and of course they are chained methods. I already know some of basic complexity of those method for example the complexity of **Array.prototype.map is O(n)**. But **when we want to determine a complexity of an algorithm, how do we manage chained method ?**

For example, consider we have a function which return for an array the sum of its positive numbers

```js
let sumPositive = arr => arr.filter(i => i > 0).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

console.log(sumPositive([1, 2, 3, -4])); // 6
console.log(sumPositive([1, 2, 3, 4])); // 10
```

Therefore, what is the **complexity of that function** ?

Another example is this algorithm which for a given string, return the counts of each character in the string

```js
let charCount = str =>  str.split('').map(
  (c,_,str) => str.filter(i => i===c)
  ).reduce((a, b) => a.hasOwnProperty(b[0]) ? a : ({...a, [b[0]]: b.length}), {});

console.log(charCount("hi")); // {"h": 1, "i": 1}

console.log(charCount("hello to you")); // {"h": 1, "e": 1, "l": 2, "o": 3, " ": 2, "t": 1, "y": 1, "u": 1}
```

So for this second I need to know especially its complexity because we are dealing with **nested method like the filter which is being call inside a map**

So any general method to determine the complexity of such algorithm are welcome.

***Note*: All the complexity in this question is the time-complexity not space**

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know O(n) * n is still O(n).  Chaining can go too far still and if performance is the issue you can often accomplish everything faster with one reduce.

Comment: But what about nested method like the one I said above

Comment: As an aside, you could use Generators to provide lazy execution to prevent multiple iterations if iterating over the same array multiple times causes performance issues. Your second example that counts characters is `O(n^2)`, as for each character in the array we must search every other character in the array in the worst case.

Comment: So could you give me an example of what I can do to improve the code or some useful links ? @DanPantry

Comment: @Dexygen I think you meant `O(n) + n`. Because shouldn't `O(n) * n` will be `n^2` like 2 * 2 will be 4.

Comment: @DebuShinobi Yes you're correct that's what I meant thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chaining methods is actually just for convenience. `map()` or `filter()` returns an array. Now you can first put a name on the array, like `let result = arr.map(...)` and then do other stuff on that `result` array, **or** you can directly do something on the array returned by `map()` (or `filter()`), like `map().filter().<more chaining if you want>`.

So, it's equivalent to a sequential execution. Consider this example,

```js
let sumPositive = arr => arr.filter(i => i > 0)
                            .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

let arr = [1, 2, 3, -4];

let filteredArray = arr.filter(i => i > 0); // O(n)
let reducedResult = filteredArray.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0); // O(n)

console.log(sumPositive(arr)); // 6
console.log(reducedResult) // 6
```

Now you see `filter()` takes `O(n)` and then `reduce()` takes `O(n)`, so you get `O(n) + O(n) ==> O(n)` as your final time complexity.

I hope you can similarly find complexity for the second example. If you need assistance, let me know in the comments.

Comment: And what about the nested method like a filter into a map ?

Comment: For each iteration inside `map()`(for all chars in string `str` of length `n`), you're performing `filter()` on `n` elements. So, `filter()` takes `O(n)` and it's done `n` times inside `map()`. That gives you `n*O(n) ==> O(n^2)`. Just try to think `for` loops. `map()` is like a `for` loop over `n` elements and inside it, you have another `for` loop over `n` elements(due to `filter()`). Hence, complexity is `O(n^2)`

Answer (score 1):

@Ajay Dabas answered your question; I'm answering your question in the comments:

> So could you give me an example of what I can do to improve the code or some useful links

Your first example isn't going to get any simpler, but you could decrease the time complexity of your second algorithm:

```
let charCount = str =>  str.split('')
  .map((c,_,str) => str.filter(i => i===c))
  .reduce((a, b) => a.hasOwnProperty(b[0]) ? a : ({...a, [b[0]]: b.length}), {});
```

You could do this by not using the `filter()` method. There's no need to do this if you maintain an index of all of the keys and their current counts.. and you're already doing that with `reduce()`:

```
    let charCount = str => 
        return str.split('').reduce(
            (acc, nextChar) => {
                return {
                    ...acc,
                    [nextChar]: (acc[nextChar] || 0) + 1
                };
            },
            Object.create(null)
        );
    };
```

This should be `O(n)` - We only iterate the array twice. Notice how we do not need to `filter()` the results because all we need to do is take the existing count for that character in the accumulator and increment it by one.

The usage of `Object.create(null)` is to create a new object with a `null` prototype - that means we don't need to use `hasOwnProperty()`.

You should keep in mind that just because something is `O(n^2)` does not mean there is a performance problem. Big O notation just describes how some code will behave as the input data increases. Only look to optimize code when you know it's a problem.